# aligning a div to the right when the inside elements have float left

Tags: html, css

I came across this pretty cool wizard menu, but I can't figure out how to align the div to the right.

http://www.emirplicanic.com/css/css-step-by-step-menu-wizard-style

```
<div class="wizard-steps">
  <div class="completed-step"><a href="#step-one"><span>1</span> Account Info</a></div>
  <div class="active-step"><a href="#step-two"><span>2</span> Contact Info</a></div>
  <div><a href="#"><span>3</span> Security Question</a></div>
  <div><a href="#"><span>4</span> Confirmation</a></div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing that is because of the float: left that is set on the inside elements.

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can fix it as:

```
.cont{
    position: absolute;
    width: 550px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

then put your wizard-steps inside:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="wizard-steps">...</div>
</div>
```

---

edit then:

```
.cont{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

then change:

```
.wizard-steps div {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at that, but I cannot have a fix width unfortunately.

Comment: i've edited my answer, however it wont work in some previous versions of IE, but i think you don't use it anyway?...

Comment: Thanks Elen, getting close now. The only problem I'm seeing at this time is in IE8 the spaces between the steps are no longer there. It looks good in IE9 and FF9.

Comment: I added a margin-left: 10px on the .wizard-steps div and changed margin-left a to 10 px as well and it looks perfect now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to give it a width. Without an explicit width, it has a width of 100% of its container. No matter how you align it, the float on the elements are going to stick to the left-hand side of .wizard-steps. So make it less than 100% wide, stick it to the right and they will appear at the new left edge.

Be aware of all the position: relative going on in there as well.

Comment: The problem is I cannot set a fixed width because that content will be generated dynamically, so it could have 3 steps, or 10 steps